# Löwenheim-Skolem downward

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I was wondering if there are some good implications of LöSko downwards why we want a Logic to have this property?

In Lindström theorem we want it to hold but I only know implications which make the logic weaker?

Thank you

Comment: Well, if a theory couched in a logic with DLS has infinite models, it then has (by DLS) countable models, which are generally more tractable than uncountable ones. In particular, one may hope to show the theory has atomic or prime models or something. Do you have anything else in mind?